# Setting onclick event removing the handlers attached before

Tags: javascript, onclick

What is the difference betwen setting the onclick function in this way:
`obj.onclick=new Function('functionname')` 
and

```
obj.onclick=function(){ functionname();};
```

How can i set the onclick event removing all previrius attached? (using jquery or simply javascript)
i try something like this:

> $(obj).unbind('click');
>
> $(obj).click(function() {
>   functionname(); 
>   });

but the unbind seems to remove even the next attached events.
thanks
EDIT:

I set the click event using jquery:

```
function ON(){ 
 $('#makecorr').unbind('click');//i unbind for some reason..    
 $('#makecorr').click(function() { OFF(); }); 
} 
function OFF(){
 $('#makecorr').unbind('click');//i want to remove prev attached fun 
 //and replace it with new event 
 $('#makecorr').click(function() { ON(); }); 
}
```

this doesnt work for me, when i click the object 'makecorr' it goes in loop , if i put an alert, it comes up infinitely
but when i use: '

```
function ON(){
$('#makecorr').get(0).onclick=new Function('OFF()');
} 
function OFF()
{
 $('#makecorr').get(0).onclick=new Function('ON()');
}
```

it works. strange where am i wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pair of lines:

```
$(obj).unbind('click');
$(obj).click(function() { functionname(); });
```

...if executed in the order above should result in just the handler you've defined there being attached. If you're seeing other behavior, it must be something else in the script.

Regarding

> What is the difference betwen setting the onclick function in this way: 
>   
> `obj.onclick=new Function('functionname')` and
>   
> `obj.onclick=function(){ functionname();};`

If you're dynamically adding handlers to an element and you're already using jQuery for other reasons, you don't want to use the `onclick` property at all; stick to the jQuery API, to avoid really confusing yourself. :-)

Even if you're not using jQuery, you almost *never* want to use `new Function(...)`. There are only very special situations where you'd need that. Mostly stick to `function() { functionname(); }` (or just use `functionname` directly).

Comment: @user354881: Recommend updating your question with that info (formatted), it's pretty close to unreadable in a comment. I'll take a look when I get back.